# Comparing two JSON in go

Tags: json, go

I am trying to compare data in JSON format in Go. I just need to check if they have both have the same structure and not the values. I was using the below code. tree and tree2 are JSON.  However, if the keys are the same and the values are different, the below code shows as false, the expected answer should be true. I appreciate any help in the direction.

```
var a1  interface{}
var a2 interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(tree), &a1)
json.Unmarshal([]byte(tree2), &a2)
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(a1,a2))
```

Comment: That depends a great deal on what you mean by "structure and not the values". I would consider the contents of a JSON array to be values, not structure; but the elements could be objects, which is structure; but two arrays of objects could have different numbers of elements, and each element could have a different structure. What you're asking is impossible in any language, at least without some restrictions on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: you might also define your json as a schema and validate both strings against the schema using a library such as https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way you can do this. You have to write a recursive comparison function, something like this:

```
func compareKeys(in1,in2 interface{}) bool {
  if m1, ok:=in1.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
     if m2, ok:=in2.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
         return compareMaps(m1,m2)
     }
     return false
  }
  if a1,ok := in1.([]interface{}); ok {
    if a2, ok:=in2.([]interface{}); ok {
       return compareArrays(a1, a2);
    }
    return false
   }
  if _, ok:=in2.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
      return false
  }
  if _, ok:=in2.([]interface{}); ok {
      return false
  }
  return true
}

func compareMaps(in1, in2 map[string]interface{}) bool {
   if len(in1)!=len(in2) {
      return false
   }
   for k,v:=range in1 {
      if v2, ok:=in2[k]; ok {
         if !compareKeys(v, v2) {
             return false
          }
       } else {
          return false
       }
   }
   return true
}


func compareArrays(in1, in2 []interface{}) bool {
  if len(in1)!=len(in2) {
     return false
  }
  for i:=range in1 {
     if !compareKeys(in1[i],in2[i]) {
       return false
     } 
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may compare jour strings like this:https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/require#JSONEqf

if assert.JSONEqf(t, `{"hello": "world", "foo": "bar"}`, `{"foo": "bar", "hello": "world"}`, "error message %s", "formatted") {
println("#############################################")
}